# I am making own c preprocessor but when I type gcc -E main.c -o main.i, in main.i I found these lines

Tags: gcc, preprocessor

I am making own c preprocessor 
but when I type gcc -E main.c -o main.i,
in main.i I found these lines

```
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "head.h" 1
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 367 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
```

can any one tell use of these lines ?